# Exporting map.graphics to image using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics

I'm developing a GIS Map Application, I'm using Esri JS API .

I have a facility to highlight some parts in the map, however I'm wondering if I can - in any way - export these graphics into an image for printing purposes.

I don't have the printing service enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a graphic using the HTML Canvas.

Here's a project where I did this: https://github.com/WSDOT-GIS/arcgis-map-thumbnail-builder